# Redirect the request to JSP in servlet giving error?

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

if i give res.sendRedirect("RequestObjectInJSP.jsp") in my servlet class it works(in this case jsp file exist at D:\apache-tomcat-6.0.33\apache-tomcat-6.0.33\webapps\hello) but if i give   res.sendRedirect("WEB-INF/classes/jsp/RequestObjectInJSP.jsp") it does not work(in this case file exist at D:\apache-tomcat-6.0.33\apache-tomcat-6.0.33\webapps\hello\WEB-INF\classes\jsp) saying requested resource is not available. Not sure what ia m missing here.Appserver is Tomcat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSPs under WEB-INF cannot be directly accessed. This is generally a Good Thing. A redirect tells the browser to request a different URL, so sending a redirect to a JSP tells the browser to directly request that JSP.

To server a JSP inside of WEB-INF, [`RequestDispatcher#forward()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/RequestDispatcher.html#forward%28javax.servlet.ServletRequest,%20javax.servlet.ServletResponse%29) to it from a servlet.